# Using where, then a relational association

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

This has come up again and again in the project I'm working on so am going to try and get an answer once and for all.

I'm trying to use where, and then collect all of an association. I can't describe the problem well so it may have been answered before (in fact, I'm sure it has) but here is an example.

I have applicant_approvals, which is a join table between a few different relations. It also has its own column, `approved`. I'm trying to get all applicant approvals where an applicant has been approved, and then get those applicants. So something like:

```
  @stage.applicant_approvals
        .where(approved: true)
        .applicants
```

Now, of course, you can't do that because `where` returns an active record association. I don't want to use first because I want all the applicants that have been approved of that stage of the process.

Is there an acknowledged way to do this or do I need to get the association, then run it through an each to get each applicant?

thanks.

Comment: You could consider going about this the other way such that `Applicant.where(id: @stage.applicant_approvals.where(approved: true).select(:applicant_id))` this will select all the applications where the subquery returns the `applicant_id` or `Applicant.joins(:applicant_approval).where(applicant_approvals: {approved: true})` but I don't know what `@stage` is in this case

Comment: `Is there an acknowledged way to do this or do I need to get the association, then run it through an each to get each applicant?` no, there is no acknowledged way (because it all depends on your relations), yes, you should run through the relation and you can use `includes` to preload them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this by setting up indirect associations:

```
class Applicant < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :applicant_approvals
  has_many :stages, through: :applicant_approvals
end

class ApplicantApproval < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :applicant
  belongs_to :stage
end

class Stage < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :applicant_approvals
  has_many :applicants, through: :applicant_approvals
end
```

Then just create pop a where clause onto the association:

```
@stage.applicants.where(applicant_approvals: { approved: true })
```